# Handling font size on different mobile device platforms without excessive code and redundancy?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm developing my first mobile app and I've just run into the reality of differing screen densities means that FontSize 20 is tiny on one platform and gigantic on another. My searching for solutions to this have so far turned up only the concept of setting up large sets of per-platform, per-density conditionals for font size using chains of OnPlatform, and I think that concept is absurd.

Surely I am not the only person who has hit his head on this wall and said "Writing out large sets of conditionals for a cornucopia of platforms is a poor use of my time". What can be done ensure a consistent font size across multiple screen densities in a more automatic way?

Comment: Are you aware of the `OnPlatform` method? https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OnPlatform/

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Of course I'm aware of the OnPlatform method. Please read and understand the question - The entire point of asking is how to not waste my time by having to use it.